MyDiffCallback reorder messes with scroll offset
So here is my problem. I have a rapidly changing UI. I am using a nested recycler view and MyDiffCallback to handle the changes.
If I am at the start of the the row and something moves infront of the first element, and then another, etc now I am at the end of the row. So I can end with the same list but now at the end of the row.
Is there a way to set the scroll offset of row of recycler views AFTER areContentsTheSame, or to lock the scroll offset to a percentage of the row? Or to not follow the units but the offset value?
